# gdb python programming: how to write code that will set breakpoints to every method of a C++ class?

Tags: c++, python, debugging, gdb

I would like to be able to set breakpoints to every method of a C++ class in gdb.
I think the easiest way to do this is probably python, since now python has complete access to gdb.  I know very little python, and with gdb on top of it, it's even harder.  I am wondering if anyone knows how to write a class python code that sets breakpoints to every method of a named class in gdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you compiled with debugging symbols, you dont even need python for this:

```
rbreak source.cpp:.
```

Comment: wow, that's great, thanks! I'm on vacation with no way to check this out, but I just looked at gdb docs, and there it is!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I just noticed you're asking for how to do this with a C++ class, not a python one. Oops. I'll leave the answer up in the hope that it will be useful to anyone debugging a python extension...

---

A bit of googling finds: [Python code can manipulate breakpoints via the `gdb.Breakpoint` class.](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Breakpoints-In-Python.html).

We can find all methods of a class like this:

```
import inspect
class Foo(object):
    bar = 1
    def baz(self):
        print "quoz"
inspect.getmembers(Foo, inspect.ismethod)
# [('baz', <unbound method Foo.baz>)]
```

Putting it together:

```
def stop_hammertime(klass):
    methods = inspect.getmembers(klass, inspect.ismethod)
    method_names = [klass.__name__ + m[0] for m in methods]
    return [gdb.Breakpoint(m) for m in method_names]
```

Note: This is untested as I don't have the `gdb` module installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate (for example using python) a .gdbrc file with a line containing 
'break C::foo'
for every function of your class C and then start gdb.

Comment: thanks, but I really want a general routine that will work when I am in gdb without getting out.  Given that tab completion will display a whole list of symbols, clearly gdb has the information.